# Python: how do you remember the order of `super`'s arguments?

Tags: python, super

As the title says, how do you remember the order of `super`'s arguments? Is there a mnemonic somewhere I've missed?

After years of Python programming, I still have to look it up :(

(for the record, it's `super(Type, self)`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inheritance makes me think of a classification **hierarchy**. And the order of the arguments to `super` is hierarchical: first the class, then the instance.

Another idea, inspired by the answer from ~unutbu:

```
class Fubb(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        # Crap, I can't remember how super() goes!?
```

Steps in building up a correct `super()` call.

```
__init__(self, *args, **kw)              # Copy the original method signature.

super(Fubb).__init__(self, *args, **kw)  # Add super(Type).
                     /
              -------
             /
super(Fubb, self).__init__(*args, **kw)  # Move 'self', but preserve order.
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply remember that the `self` is *optional* - `super(Type)` gives access to unbound superclass methods - and optional arguments always come last.

Comment: Ah, also interesting — I hadn't realized that.

Answer (score 5):

I don't. In Python 3 we can just write

```
super().method(params)
```

Comment: Interesting. Still on Python 2.6 so have not seen this yet (although I'm not really sure at the moment if I think this `looks` more elegant / correct)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, `super` is used inside of a `class` definition. There, (again typically), the first argument to `super` should always be the name of the `class`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kw):
        super(Foo,self).__init__(*args,**kw)
```